# Ethernet Frame in Python

Tags: python, raw-sockets

How to create an ethernet frame in python with a specification of VLAN?

I have the IP and TCP header ready. I need to attach the ethernet header to it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/):

```
from scapy import inet
newpkt = inet.Ether()/inet.Dot1Q(vlan=1)/inet.IP()
```

There are many tutorials... You can start with this: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html

If you wanna play with sockets, you can find a good example at https://github.com/osrg/openvswitch/blob/master/utilities/ovs-vlan-test.in

Comment: well i am aware of scapy. But I do not want to use scapy becasue it is slow :/